# The most efficient algorithm to find most occurring number in a set of 4 numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, byte

I am reading four files byte by bytes and comparing all four of those bytes to make one final byte from those four bytes. The way it works is:

1. If all bytes are `0`, then output `0`
2. If all but 1 byte are `0`, then output the odd-byte-out (If the bytes were `0, 0, 1, 0`, then I would output a `1`)
3. If 2 bytes are `0`, then I randomly output one of the non-`0` bytes
4. If 1 byte is `0`, then I output the most occurring byte from the other 3, or otherwise in case of a tie I output a random byte from that set
5. If all bytes are non-`0`, then I output the most occurring byte, or otherwise in case of a tie I output a random byte from that set

One important thing to note is that "random" does not literally have to be random, I can choose the most convenient one.

So I have given this some thought, but I still cannot come up with the absolute fastest way of getting an output from these numbers. One thing I noticed those is if the first two bytes I read are the same and non-zero, then I can skip the next two bytes and just output one of the first two bytes. If the first three bytes are `0`, then I can output the last byte. I can also check the third byte with the first byte and second byte to see if they are equal so I can avoid going onto the 4th byte, but I need this to be literally as efficient as possible. I need to run over this algorithm about 8 billion times, and so every little bit counts =)

So anyways, what is the most efficient way to go about doing this? (pseudocode? or otherwise)

This is what the program looks like (the shell of it at least):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class reconstructerv2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      FileInputStream in1 = null;
      FileInputStream in2 = null;
      FileInputStream in3 = null;
      FileInputStream in4 = null;
      FileOutputStream out = null;  

      try {
         in1 = new FileInputStream("1.dd");
         in2 = new FileInputStream("2.dd");
         in3 = new FileInputStream("3.dd");
         in4 = new FileInputStream("4.dd");
         BufferedInputStream in1b = new BufferedInputStream(in1);
         BufferedInputStream in2b = new BufferedInputStream(in2);
         BufferedInputStream in3b = new BufferedInputStream(in3);
         BufferedInputStream in4b = new BufferedInputStream(in4);
         out = new FileOutputStream("final.dd");
         int a;
         int b;
         int c;
         int d;
         int o; 

         while ((a = in1.read()) != -1) {
            b = in2.read();
            if (a == b && a != 0)
               o = a;
            else {
               c = in3.read();
               d = in4.read();
            }
            System.out.println((byte) c);
            out.write((byte) o);
         }
      } finally {
         if (in1 != null) {
            in1.close();
            in2.close();
            in3.close();
            in4.close();
         }
         if (out != null) {
            out.close();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT: 8 billion, not 8 million

EDIT2: As pointed out in the comments, I can't skip reading over characters due to synchronization.

Comment: are you sure that this is not premature optimization? did you have perfomance issues with actual implementation? did you benchmark it?

Comment: Over 8 million times in what period? I suspect that a simple but inefficient approach would still be done in far less than a second on a decent processor. I'm absolutely sure you don't need it to be "literally as efficient as possible". (Consider a 4GB lookup table, with a pre-computed result for every possible sequence of 4 bytes. In terms of time, that may well be the most efficient approach. I doubt that it's the best one for you to use here though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Well i mean reading one byte and outputting it in itself takes a while. For 8gbs worth of bytes, thats more than 12 hours (for my computer atleast, I did a simple test to see how long it took to read and write 1mb)

Comment: what about you post some code...

Comment: @Groo bytes meaning two hexadecimal characters or as Java sees it, a number from -128 to 127

Comment: @Frank Uh I can do that but this is an algorithm problem

Comment: @Sidd: On a drive? You must have a slow disk, or be reading it very slowly :) On a good SSD, you should be able to read 8GB in far less than a minute.

Comment: @JonSkeet Could it be the fact that it is Java trying to read and write it?

Comment: No, it's the fact that he's reading/writing it byte by byte.

Comment: @Sidd: If you're reading the bytes from disk and writing the result to disk, that will almost *certainly* dwarf the time taken to do this in a clear, easy to read way... so you're probably optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: @Sidd: according to your implementation I highly doubt that the operation in itself is the bottleneck. I'd say that I/O is. You will gain a lot more by buffering input and output to disk that by trying to save 3 opcodes for the algorithm itself.

Comment: As @JonSkeet mentioned, you are most likely reading it in a very slow manner. 4 x 8 million bytes is mere 32MB, you can load these files entirely into memory (or at least increase r/w buffers).

Comment: @Sidd: Yes, the fact that you're reading and writing from *unbuffered* streams, one byte at a time, is going to kill your performance. Again, the time for your algorithm here will be *completely insignificant* compared with the gain you can make by fixing your IO.

Comment: @JonSkeet wowowowo my bad...i mean 8 billion...so sorry about that..But i am guessing your answer sticks regardless?

Comment: @Groo Sorry 8 billion bytes across 4 files, so 8gbs (My mistake on the million)

Comment: Wait, is it correct that the first four files are synced -- you're building a sort of "vote" recovery of a data vector? If that's the case, you *cannot* skip reading c and d, or your data would get out of synchronization.

Comment: @lserni That is a really interesting point. I didn't think about that. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Olaf Dietsche did: I was writing his same answer, even if I hadn't noticed the unset variable. I added a comment which might perhaps be useful, though.

Comment: Also, was my hunch that this is some sort of unstable media data recovery scheme correct? If so, there is more to consider.

Comment: @lserni Would you be willing to discuss this with me real quick in the chatroom? You are actually spot on. (by the way, i would completely understand if you can't for any reason)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18687/discussion-between-lserni-and-sidd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If all bytes are 0, then output 0

Output a+b+c+d.

> If all but 1 byte are 0, then output the odd-byte-out (If the bytes were 0,0,1,0, then I would output a 1)

Same as above. This already saves you a case. If any three bytes are zero, output the sum.

> If 2 bytes are 0, then I randomly output one of the non-0 bytes
>   If 1 byte is 0, then I output the most occurring byte from the other 3, or otherwise in case of a tie I output a random byte from that set
>   If all bytes are non-0, then I output the most occurring byte, or otherwise in case of a tie I output a random byte from that set

These cases are really all the same. Output the most-occurring of the non-zero bytes, or a random one in the event of a tie.

So there are really only two cases to consider: at least three zero bytes, and two or fewer.

As a matter of fact *all* the cases are the same. You can apply the second solution above to all the cases. It may well be quicker not to separate them at all.

But first added BufferedInputStreams around those FileInputStreams.

Comment: Will do on the bufferedinputstreams

Comment: In your case, make sure to make the buffers big, and all of the same size.

Comment: Not so much "big" as "carefully chosen". Doing lots of I/O and lots of interwoven calculations means that the performance-versus-buffer size curve is probably going to look humped. He really wants to be at the peak - not too little, not too big. See http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/input_stream_buffer_size.shtml . Depending on filesystem, OS and media, you might find the sweet spot at 2K, 4K, 8K, 16K (or, rarely, in between).

Comment: @lserni I wouldn't describe this as 'lots of interwoven calculations'. I would almost certainly use 8k and forget about it.

Comment: Well..those BufferedInputStreams were the real solution to this problem....sped up like CRAZY...it made my program go from writing one megabyte in 10 seconds to writing multiple megabytes in 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

This while loop won't work:

```
while ((a = in1.read()) != -1) {
    b = in2.read();
    if (a == b && a != 0)
        o = a;
    else {
        c = in3.read();
        d = in4.read();
    }
    System.out.println((byte) c);
    out.write((byte) o);
}
```

because sometimes you read file1 and file2 and sometimes you read all four files.

Another point: when you read all four files `o` is unset or has the value from an earlier round. This also applies to `c`, if you only read file1 and file2. So, in order to fix this, you *always* must read all four files and then the performance of your loop doesn't matter that much.

Comment: Probably, it would be worth it to experiment with different `BufferedInputStream` sizes (size1 K), and read from them into contiguous memory in blocks of varying sizes (size2 K). Depending on the architecture, I would expect a significant performance difference for different values of size1 and size2.

Comment: @lserni BufferedInputStream is pretty pointless when reading into arrays, and reading from a BufferedInputStream into an array larger than its buffer completely bypasses the buffer.

Comment: @EJP Which doesn't apply here. The files are read character by character, aren't they?

Comment: Correct. I am addressing @lserni's suggestion of using `BufferedInputStreams` and 'read[ing] from them into contiguous memory', i.e. into arrays.